# Code explanation Scrolltop

Tags: javascript, function, split, scrolltop

Can someone please explain what this code does.. Like the 'split' function etc.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var id=this.id.split('[');
    var d_id=id[1].split(']')
    var ii=d_id[0]
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('[id='+ii+']').offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: I don't see how we can give you any more info than Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It attaches a click eventhandler to every `<button>` tag.
2. In the handler it extracts the "foo" from the button's id attribute if it is for example "bar[foo]".
3. It animates a page scroll to the postition of the element with the "foo" id (the "[id=...]" jQuery selector).

The `string.split` is a string function which splits the string into an array based on the given separator, here "[" and then "]", check the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

Briefly, the `offset()` jQuery function returns the top and left pixel coordinates of the first element matched by the given selector, check the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/offset/).

So as a result, when you click a `<button>` with id "bar[foo]", the page will do an animated vertical scroll so that the element with id "foo" will be at the top or the window.

Comment: If I took the effort to answer instead of voting down the question and redirecting to Google, would you please accept the answer?